# Large excel (in terms of calculations) producing data for graphs to be published automatically

Tags: xml, excel, graph, google-sheets

I have a large excel file that produces a lot calculation.

The results are used to produce ~20 'complex' graphs

I want these graphs to be published on a joomla website and i want them to be refreshed 'instantaneously' (or with a small delay) when i refresh my workbook

**What i'm currently using:**

- windows 7
- excel 2013
- joomla 3.2.2 hosted on OVH

**What i've up-to-now tried**

- My first idea was to save my excel as a google spreadsheet (on google drive) and benefit from their publishable graphs. It works fine but as there are so many calculations in my workbook, it's (really) too slow to refresh the google spreadsheet 
  -> so that's not an option..
- My second idea was to keep my excel and prepare the data(*) required for the graphs in a dedicated worksheet in the same excel file. Then use ftp and transfer this range to a xml file

(*) The data has the following column structure

- GraphId
- Id
- Type
- Role
- Variable
- SubVariable
- M1  (First month)
- M2   (Second Month)
- ...
- M36 (36th month)

Then the xml has the following structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<dataset>
<record>
<GraphId>GraphId</GraphId>
<Id>Id</Id>
<Type>Type</Type>
<Role>Role</Role>
<Variable>Variable</Variable>
<SubVariable>SubVariable</SubVariable>
<m1>m1</m1>
<m2>m2</m2>
<m3>m3</m3>
<m4>m4</m4>
<m5>m5</m5>
<m6>m6</m6>
<m7>m7</m7>
<m8>m8</m8>
<m9>m9</m9>
<m10>m10</m10>
<m11>m11</m11>
<m12>m12</m12>
<m13>m13</m13>
<m14>m14</m14>
<m15>m15</m15>
<m16>m16</m16>
<m17>m17</m17>
<m18>m18</m18>
<m19>m19</m19>
<m20>m20</m20>
<m21>m21</m21>
<m22>m22</m22>
<m23>m23</m23>
<m24>m24</m24>
<m25>m25</m25>
<m26>m26</m26>
<m27>m27</m27>
<m28>m28</m28>
<m29>m29</m29>
<m30>m30</m30>
<m31>m31</m31>
<m32>m32</m32>
<m33>m33</m33>
<m34>m34</m34>
<m35>m35</m35>
<m36>m36</m36>
</record>
```

I transfer this xml file to my website so that it's accessible via the url http://< mywebsite >/tmp/file.xml

Then in another google spreadsheet (other than the one i mentionned earlier), i use the IMPORTXML function

=IMPORTXML(http://< mywebsite >/tmp/file.xml, "//dataset//record//")

It also works fine (:-) ) meaning i get the content of my xml file in a google spreadhseet. So i can create my graphs and publish them...
BUT it's not automatically refreshed when i refresh my excel workbook (i've created a VBA macro that automatically put my xml file on my website when i refresh my excel workboook)
because the IMPORTXML function in google spreadsheet is refreshed only at one(or two) -hour(s) interval...

I've read a lot about adding the googleclock() function in old google spreadsheets, but i'm using new google spreadsheets

Up-to-now the way i found was to refresh the importxml function was to remove the last character of the url then submit and then retype the last character and then resubmit.. not that automatic huh...:-(

Any valuable idea is welcome..

**EDIT**

Finally i found the answer by entering a new google form in my google spreadhsheet

I added one text input form that should contain the name of my xml file

Then by using the info here
http://justingale.com/2013/09/url-tricks-for-google-forms-pre-populate-and-automatically-submitting-responses/

and by adding some VBA code

```
Dim httpRequest As XMLHTTP
Set httpRequest = New XMLHTTP


httpRequest.Open "POST", "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/<yourFormKey>/formResponse?ifq", False
httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
httpRequest.send "entry.<yourEntryKey>=<yourValue>&submit=Submit"

'Check result in the following vars
a = httpRequest.Status
b = httpRequest.statusText
```

where

- < yourFormKey > is the key of the google form (you can find it the
  url of the form
- < yourEntryKey > can be found by taking a look at the source code of
  the form (find for "entry." in the sourcecode)
- < yourvalue > is the value you want to push in the google form

Then when exporting the data in the xml file and executing this piece of code, the google form attached to the google spreadsheet will contain as last record the name of the file

Then you can just execute the following formula to retrieve it

```
=index('Form Responses 5'!B:B,match(max('Form Responses 5'!A:A),'Form Responses 5'!A:A,0))
```

where 
 - 'Form Responses 5' is the name (between single quotes) of the sheet containing the form results

Then by entering the following formula

```
=IMPORTXML("http://< mywebsite >/tmp/"& index('Form Responses 5'!B:B,match(max('Form Responses 5'!A:A),'Form Responses 5'!A:A,0)), "//dataset//record//")
```

i'm getting the data refreshed automatically :-)

Comment: A bit of research suggests that Google spreadsheets has an API, so it's probably best to use that to directly transfer the data in the second approach instead of using XML. Though, not sure that'll provide your fast updates.